# Why Watson's Speech to Text gets called multiple times

Tags: unity-game-engine, watson

recently I added a voice control interface to my unity game. What puzzles me is that when I say some word to the mic, the OnSpeechInput event is fired multiple times, even what I said was just a single word. This makes it almost impossible to control the game object. Why did this happen and if I want to detect an individual voice command, what's the best practice?

Comment: I don't know specifically why this happens with Watson but you could implement a counter trap - e.g. in pseudocode watsonCount++,  if watsonCount == 1 do stuff, otherwise, don't. After a period of time with no watson, watsonCount = 0

Comment: Tried the solution and improved a bit, but the problem still occurs =( it seems that the accuracy of Waston is still not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be called multiple time untill process is over.

You can check for end of processing in response with variable
final:true.